# How to show partial FormattedText?

Tags: wpf, text, drawing

In WPF 4.0, the FormattedText class requires at least to have enough vertical space to show a line and enough horizontal space to show a character, else shows nothing.

Is there a way to force FormattedText to generate the text characters partially?

By the way, I want this to show big text (e.g. with Arial 72)

Comment: What do you mean with "enough space"? Do you set the `MaxTextWidth` or `MaxTextHeight` properties?

Comment: Yes, MaxTextWidth and MaxTextHeight are setted as the available space inside a graphic symbol (e.g. a rectangle). But sometimes the space is not enough to show complete chars and gets vanished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but instead of limiting the text size by `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight`, couldn't you clip the text by [pushing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pushclip.aspx) a clip rectangle onto the DrawingContext?

Comment: I see, FormattedText cannot do what I wanted. Instead I should put my text inside an graphic context to be clipped. Thanks!